# Uncaught Error with three.js | show a 3d model on page

Tags: reactjs, three.js, jsx, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to show a GLTF(.gltf) 3d model on my website and I'm pretty sure that I've tested this code before but now it's not working with some errors in my browser's console :
**Uncaught Error: R3F: FirstBracelet is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? See: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#using-3rd-party-objects-declaratively**

here is the code :

**Experience.jsx:**

```
import { OrbitControls, Stage } from "@react-three/drei";
import { firstBracelet } from "./FirstBracelet";

export const Experience = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Stage
        intensity={1.5}
        environment="city"
        shadows={{
          type: "accumulative",
          color: "#d9afd9",
          colorBlend: 2,
          opacity: 2,
        }}
        adjustCamera={0.9}
      >
        <firstBracelet />
      </Stage>
      <OrbitControls
        makeDefault
        minPolarAngle={0}
        maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
      />

    </>
  );
};
```

**FirstBracelet.jsx:**

```
/*
Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx
*/

import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export function firstBracelet(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('./models/firstBracelet.gltf')
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Diamond.geometry} material={materials['Material #31']} position={[-4.208, -0.481, -2.67]} rotation={[1.654, -0.025, -1.124]} scale={22.256} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Gold.geometry} material={materials['Material #25']} position={[-4.208, -0.481, -2.67]} rotation={[1.654, -0.025, -1.124]} scale={22.256} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.LOGO.geometry} material={materials['Material #34']} position={[-6.861, 0.128, 6.297]} rotation={[-2.154, -0.174, -2.156]} scale={0.15} />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('./models/firstBracelet.gltf')
```

I tried adding `extend({firstBracelet});` to **Experience.jsx** but it didn't work. still doesn't show my 3d model with same errors in my console.